# change the font size relatively

Tags: css

I don't know how much is the default font size, but anyway I want to reduce it by 2px.

```
<td style='width:30%; margin:0 5%; text-align:left;vertical-align:top;font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;' font-size:'xx'>Some text</td>
```

What to assign the `font-size` attribute so that my text will be 2 pixels smaller. Thanx.

Comment: 2 pixels smaller on your monitor, using your browser settings, will not be 2 pixels smaller on other machines. Either specify the size of the parent elements text, then reduce the childs, or use a relative unit such as `em` or `ex`.

Comment: @Usman, no ufortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use em's instead of pixels.  Em's are represented in percentages relative to everything else so

```
font-size: .8em;
```

Would make it 80% of the size as the text around it.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp for a good explanation on CSS units.

Comment: Hi, `.8em` will work if you test `font-size` without using `font-family`.

Comment: @Malloc that really shouldn't affect it.  Also, you have a typo in the paste above next to font-family , your ' is making the font-size not get interpreted.

Comment: This does not answer the question how to make text 2 pixels smaller. If the question was misguided (as I think it was), it should be corrected, instead of accepting a non-answer.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't know how to unanswer questions is that something I can do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you really truly want to have it `2px` smaller, and you're happy to accept this'll only work on modern browsers:

```
font-size: calc(1em - 2px);
```

References:

Compatibility information at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Documentation at [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc), or [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc)